# Java generics holding same type of parameters more than once

Tags: java, hadoop, generics, mapreduce

I'm learning hadoop map-reduce algorithm, I'm new to java generics concepts, I can able to understand what generics can do(typecasting) for the objects created using a reference type. But could not understand why **same parameter type** is declared **more than once** inside <> braces.

Below is a reducer class definition which implements **Reducer** interface with type declaration as < Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable >. Why cant it be as < Text, IntWritable > alone ?

```
public static class T_Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements 
Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
{  

   public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
     { 
        ......
        ......
     } 
}
```

I have google it a lot and could not find a simple proper answer.

Comment: short answer: those are for input key, input value, output key, output value types. input and output types can be different. Thus, you need 4 parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaDoc for [`Reducer`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html) fully specifies the signature of the type like

> ```
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce
>      Class Reducer<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>
> ```

Which indicates that the first two parameters are the key and value types for the input to the reduce function - while the second pair are the **output** types. Here they are the same, but they are not required to be for every possible use case. For example, you might be producing a `double` from computation on `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Reducer *can* take four different types. In your case, it doesn't, but the functionality is still there, and the compiler would have not idea what the last two types were with something like:

```
Reducer<Text, IntWritable, ?, ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the declaration for `Reducer`?  My guess is it is declared as `Reducer<T,U,V,W>` so you have to parameterize all of the types, even if some of them are the same.

Answer (score 1):

`Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>` is a specialization of `Reducer<K2, V2, K3, V3>`. The interface does not require that `K2` and `K3` be the same type. So it cannot reuse the parameter for the key type. Therefore specializations​ cannot, either.